# Client side only markdown website

Tags: javascript, markdown, static-site

Single page Javascript app in browser that will fetch markdown files from public directory on same server and on the fly render it to HTML.
It will be static on server(except to on the fly provide file listings to frontend app), because it is just markdown files. No need to generate anything.
Dynamic on client. To add content simply place .md files to open directory, on next load web app will fetch those files.
It is possible to implement this. What drawbacks of this architecture ?

Comment: i recommend require.js + text.js

Comment: [Yes](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) [it's](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) [possible](http://www.showdown.im/). But why don't you just pre-render to HTML? The answer to that question may help answer your question about the drawbacks.

Comment: Not pre-render just because we can, and I don't think that we should.